# Delete records from table according to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have two tables in MYSQL that looks something like this:

Table A:

```
id1  |  id2  |  id3  |  id4  |
 1   |   15  |   26  |   12  |
 2   |   27  |   12  |   15  |
 1   |   4   |   82  |   18  |
 4   |   11  |   37  |   22  |
 1   |   21  |   31  |   24  |
```

Table b:

```
id1  |  id2  |
 2   |   27  | 
 1   |   21  |
```

I want to delete the rows in table A that have the partial match of fields in Table B (meaning delete rows 2 and 5 from table A).

does anyone have an idea?
Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Exists` or `Join` syntax to delete the matched records. Try this

```
delete 
from TableA
where exists 
(
select 1 
from TableB B 
where TableA.id1 = B.id1 and TableA.id2 = B.id2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the multi-table delete syntax:

```
delete TableA.* 
from TableA
inner join TableB on TableB.id1 = TableA.id1 and TableB.id2 = TableA.id2;
```